# Magento2 : Product list phtml file for each page

Tags: magento2, php, frontend, product-list

I want to change the frontend of product list page like in picture below. What file should i change? The product list i mean is each product list in each home page and category page.

Product List :
[image: product list]

Comment: Do you want to do this by theme or module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So a quick answer on this :

**You can find the list.phtml in `catalog_category_view.xml`**

under the line of

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

If you want to change default logics behind the class you can extend `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` and use that in your own Block that replaces this one.

If you just want to change html things you can just replace `Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml`

In your theme copy the file under `Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

and ajust it how you would like.

If you want to replace it by Module you need to have a `view/frontend` folder withing your module directory and adjust the xml by using referenceBlocks :

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml
```

**with the code :**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_module::product/list.phtml">
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and then have a

```
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

copy/paste the Magento list.phtml there.

Notice how in the list.phtml it sometimes calls for `ChildBlocks` . Childblocks are blocks that are defined within a level 0 block (so container->block->childblocks). These are not outputted unless you call them in your phtml fille by using the ->getChildBlock() function.

**If you want to adjust the those you will need to do the same thing for**

```
            <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" />
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container" name="category.product.addto" as="addto">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\AddTo\Compare"
                       name="category.product.addto.compare" as="compare"
                       template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
            </block>
            <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
            </action>
```

**For example :**

Magento calls for `'$block->getChildBlock('addto'))->getChildHtml('compare')'`

You can find this in the file `Magento_Catalog::product/list/addto/compare.phtml`

**More information**

If you are new to this its a lot of information to take in. I suggest you look at the following info page :

> http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html