# Include custom template file in catalog listing page in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1

I am using Magento 2.3.1, I wanted to include the custom template in product listing page for all products just above the add to cart button as shown in the attachment.

[image]

Below is my code I tried.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="product_list">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="yousave" template="MyVendor_MyModule::yousave.phtml" after="additional" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

and template is

```
<?php echo 'hello world'; ?>
```

but I am not getting proper output

Comment: product listing page ??

Comment: yes, product listing page

Comment: add wherever you want in list.phtml file `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("MyVendor_MyModule::yousave.phtml")->toHtml();?>`

Comment: please add your yousave.phtml file code

Comment: if i want to add above code directly into list.phtml i would have done it. but i wanted to add from external module to list.phtml

Comment: @RkRathod my yousave.phtml code is <?php echo 'hello world'; ?>

Comment: Please review this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/198147

Comment: @Shorabh i dont want to touch list.phtml code. if i write xml it should come in the list.phtml

Comment: you want to change position of your custom text without override the list.phtml file ???

Comment: i want to include my custom text phtml without overriding list.phtml

Answer (score 0):

You have to call getChildHtml('yousave') ; ?> in your list.phtml

and add the below code in listing xml file.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct"  name="yousave" template="Magento_Catalog::product/yousave.phtml"/>
```

Note: you can override the file as per your convenience.